How should I test for parallel trend assumption in a repeated cross-sectional data?
I have a repeated cross-sectional dataset on time-use which I am using to estimate the impact of a certain shock. My outcome of interest is time spent by certain individual on particular activity. There are two rounds of data available before the shock happened and one round of data after the shock.
I am curious to know how I can test for parallel trend assumption in this case using Stata.

Hello Jheelum. Welcome to CV. Are you solely interested in getting some Stata code or the underlying principles involved?

@User1865345 asks a good question, but, as a newcomer, you may not realize why. Requests for code are off topic here. So, if that's what you want, the question will be closed (you could try to ask on a Stata list).

I would like to know the underlying principles involved

Welcome. Two rounds pre-shock may be insufficient. Can you acquire more data before the shock?

Thanks for the reply. However the time period of the available data leaves me with two rounds of pre-event data and one post-event data. Can I request for advice in this case?
